# Populate Account Number when the user click Account lookup field

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]I want to populate Account Number when the user click Account lookup field,but i got this error
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Error is in expression '{!AccountPopulated}' in page lookup_populate
Class.Lookup_populate.AccountPopulated: line 8, column 1.

```
    public class Lookup_populate{

    public String AccNo{get;set;}
    public Id AccountId;
 public Account cont {get{cont = new Account();}set;} 
public pagereference AccountPopulated()
{
    cont=[select AccountNumber from Account where id=:cont.ParentId limit 1];
    AccNo= cont.AccountNumber;
    return null;
}
}
<apex:page controller="Lookup_populate" >
    <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="accinfo" title="Account Information">
    <apex:actionRegion >
      <apex:inputField value="{!cont.ParentId}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!AccountPopulated}" rerender="accinfo"/> 
         </apex:inputField>
         </apex:actionRegion>
         <apex:inputText value="{!AccNo}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>  
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have getter setter on Contact and hence follwoing change in query should solve your problem

```
public class Lookup_populate{

public String AccNo{get;set;}
public Id AccountId;
public Account cont {get;set;} 

public Lookup_populate(){
   cont =new Account ();
}

   public pagereference AccountPopulated(){
  cont=[select AccountNumber,ParentId  from Account where id=:cont.ParentId limit 1];
  AccNo= cont.AccountNumber;
  return null;
  }
 }

   <apex:page controller="Lookup_populate" >
   <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Information">
     <apex:inputField value="{!cont.ParentId}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!AccountPopulated}" rerender="accinfo"/> 
       </apex:inputField>
       <apex:outputPanel >
       <apex:inputText value="{!AccNo}" id="accinfo"/>
       </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>  
    </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

The basic problem is AccountId is coming null and i dont see  you are populating the same .Using the reference should solve the problem

Comment: thanks for reply I have tried this one it gives the same error.

Comment: edited the answer .The instance should be inside getter

Comment: thanks for reply I have tried this but i getting this error
Error: Lookup_populate Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement. at line 4 column 28

Comment: hey if you use pagereference return null else on void dont return anything.Please see the return type

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but i getting the same error and i add a error image

Comment: what current code are you using ?Please paste in question ,I will help on this

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12005/discussion-between-udaya-and-mohith-kumar)